# How to unit test that a radio button is setting state var correctly in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I have a state var:

```
@State var gameType: Int = 1
```

and I have two radio buttons that set it to either 1 or 2:

```
gameTypeRadioButtonView(index: 1, selectedIndex: $gameType)
gameTypeRadioButtonView(index: 2, selectedIndex: $gameType)
```

I did a record UI Unit test that launches the app and clicks the button to set gameType from its initial default of 1 to 2

How do I validate that in the unit test? Like there's plenty of samples for statictext and others, but I can't find anything for just verifying that the radio button did the thing.

related: how would one test that text that should only be visible when gameType is 2 is working? i.e.:

```
 if gameType != 1 {
     Text("Blue Score")
     Text(String(bluePlayerScore))
     .frame(width: 25, height: 22, alignment: .center)
 }
```

(yes, I know I can test this other ways, but it's a class project and they want unit tests so...)